# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{1+{1\over 2}+\cdots +{1\over n}\over (\pi ^n +e^n)^{1\over n}\log_e n}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{1+{1\over 2}+\cdots +{1\over n}\over (\pi ^n +e^n)^{1\over n}\log_e n}.$$

My attempt: $${1\over \pi}\lim_{n\to \infty}{1+{1\over 2}+\cdots +{1\over n}\over (1 +({e\over \pi})^n)^{1\over n}\log_e n}={1\over \pi}\lim_{n\to \infty}{1+{1\over 2}+\cdots +{1\over n}\over \log_e n}={1\over \pi}\times 1.$$

As $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 +({e\over \pi})^n)^{1\over n}=1$.

Is there any mistake in this. If so please rectify this. Also any other way to solve this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the prerequisites of the course you're taking, it might look good. Since we don't know the prerequisites of the course, it is hard to judge if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}{1+{1\over 2}+\cdots +{1\over n}\over (\pi ^n +e^n)^{1\over n}\log_e n}.$$
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n}{\ln n}\lim_{n \to \infty} (\pi^n+e^n)^{-1/n}$$
By Euler's asynptotic result $1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4+..+1/n\sim \ln n$, we can write
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\pi^n+e^n)^{-1/n}.$$
Next by sqeeze law $$\pi^n<(\pi^n+e^n)<2\pi^n \implies 2^{-1/n}\pi^{-1} <(\pi^n+e^n)^{-1/n} < \pi^{-1}.$$
Hence $L=\frac{1}{\pi}.$

Answer (score 2):

For
$$ a_{n} = \frac{H_{n}}{(\pi ^n +e^n)^{1\over n} \, \ln n}, $$
where $H_{n}$ is the harmonic number, it can be seen that
$$ H_{n} \approx \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2 \, n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
and $\frac{e}{\pi} < 1$ which gives
$$ \left(\pi^n + e^n \right)^{1/n} = \pi \, \left(1 + \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^n \right)^{1/n} = \pi \, \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \, \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^n + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right). $$
Now,
$$ a_{n} \approx \frac{1 + \frac{\gamma}{\ln n} + \frac{1}{2 \, n \, \ln n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{\pi \, \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \, \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^n + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) }. $$
Taking the desired limit leads to
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \, a_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi}. $$

Comment: Were expansions up to that order necessary or could you stop at a lower one if you just wanted to get the limit?